# UIButton in UICollectionViewCell resets its label text to what is set using storyboards from the runtime text being set on every click

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on an app having a collection view with Collection view cells having 4 buttons to invoke different actions.Each links to a different IBAction. I have read multiple threads across the board and had decided to use storyboards rather than go at it programmatically since 'this could be the way forward'. So while setting up the buttons, I had set default label text to Button 1, Button 2 etc. In the code, while giving cell for index path, I am changing the button text to something programmatically. When the application is run the cells render fine with dequeueing, and the text being set programmatically is set correctly. However, when I click any of the buttons, the action is called, but the label text of the button resets to what was set using storyboards.

I have tried everything to retain the text label copy to what it should be. But to no avail. When I again dequeue the cell by scrolling across the collection view and the view gets redrawn, the button again gets the correct text.

Can anyone please shed some light on why the button text for a button placed in a collection cell will reset its text and will not allow it to be set unless the view is redrawn.. Also any ideas on how to fix this.

Thanks a ton

Comment: how do you set the label text?

Answer (score 5):

deej nailed it --

I had the same problem but was doing something stupid:

```
self.btnProperty.titleLabel.text = @"button title";
```

rather than:

```
[self.btnProperty setTitle:@"button title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Use the latter.